# One call to contract function generates multiple transactions

Tags: web3js

I am adding functionality to the Truffle Pet Shop example dApp. I have created a returnPet function in the solidity contract, and have tested it via console and test contracts. I would now like to call it in my JS app.

The problem is, when I call it, the handleReturn() function,

```
handleReturn: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

    var adoptionInstance;

    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        adoptionInstance = instance;

        return adoptionInstance.returnPet(petId);
      }).then(function(result) {
        return App.markAdopted();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
```

generates multiple transactions, and does not affect the blockchain (a different problem. If you have answers to this, I would love to hear them.). As far as I can tell, handleReturn() only gets called once, so why is it generating multiple transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
handleReturn: function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var petId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));

var adoptionInstance;

web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  var account = accounts[0];

});
App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    adoptionInstance = instance;
  })
  adoptionInstance.returnPet(petId).then(function(result) {
    return App.markAdopted();
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

It calling multiple transactions because you are calling it under the web3.eth.getAccounts methods,if it doesn't work call your contract methods/fuctions using truffle by importing your contracrt artifacts and use webpack to bundle it

Comment: Haven't tested this yet, but your answer of me using the getAccounts() method was right.